# Is "IAP" a synonym of "microtransactions?"

Tags: discussion, tags

We've had [microtransactions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microtransactions) for some time now. We've recently created [iap](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iap). Are these tags the same (and thus, should [iap](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iap) be a synonym of [microtransactions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microtransactions))?

Note that the excerpt for [microtransactions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microtransactions) currently contains the text "also referred to as... in-app purchasing."

Comment: The next question is "Do we need such tags?" Can one be an expert in micro-transactions? In IAP? Or are they expert with a specific IAP implementation, as suggested by [Draco18s answer](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2401/40264)?

Comment: That's probably a separate question. I don't think "IAP" specifically refers only to Google Play's API in general, as implied (although the two uses of the tag currently do). I do think the tags should remain, as I think one can definitely be interested in the more soft-science aspects of microtransactions relating to effective strategies and display, and such.

Comment: Yup, different question :) Maybe we'll need to revisit it when there are more questions tagged with these tags.

Comment: I just realized that there is this tag which is already used [tag:in-app-purchase]; you might want to merge them together and make on synonym of the other.

Comment: Good find; done.

Comment: Originally, "microtransactions" implied size.  That is, they are literally "micro" "transactions".  They were supposed to be tiny tiny payments of like 1 cent, or fractions of a cent.  I don't think that anybody doing IAP is using "microtransactions" at all, at least by the original meaning of the word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think microtransactions and IAP are two different concepts:

- microtransactions deals with the business model
- iap deals with *an* implementation of the business model.

You can very well create a game that has no *in-app*-purchase but has microtransactions (what if you need to go on the website of the MMO to do the transaction), and you can have in-app purchase without it being a microtransation (you can buy the full game).

They should not be synonyms, and the text of microtransactions should be modified to remove the part about in-app billing.

Comment: This is a good point; I was originally leaning towards the idea that they're fundamentally the same, but now I do think it might be premature to merge them. We don't really have the distinctions you've defined in actual practice, yet, but merging them would make codifying that distinction much harder.

Comment: Agreed. Further, I think it's possible to be an expert in each of these topics, making both relevant tags. An expert in microtransactions would be someone like a monetization designer, with experience in designing mechanics to work with purchasable content, and in pricing/balancing this content. An expert on In-App Purchases would be someone like a developer with experience in store APIs & payment platforms, or a UI/UX designer with experience developing storefront interfaces. While these skillsets can often overlap, I think it's good to distinguish "what can players buy" vs "how do they buy"

Comment: I see the distinctions you make but I do think the words are used interchangeably in many cases. Would a new user posting a question or searching for answers make such a distinction?

Comment: @TartleWizard If there is potential confusion, I suppose we could make the distinction clear in the tag usage.

Answer (score 3):

## Yes

In-App Purchases (IAP) should be a synonym of [microtransactions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microtransactions) as there is no way to do one without doing the other (although a $100 price tag might not be considered *micro* the code, apis, and so on involved are identical).

The only case I can see for having them be separate is is [iap](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iap) is referring to a *specific* microtransaction API, in which case it should be renamed (assuming we want the tag) to accurately reflect that, e.g. [google-play-iap](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-play-iap) or [unity-iap](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity-iap).